# QSlider with icons

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, qslider

Given a set of images, I'd like to move a `QSlider` such that every step shows a little thumbnail icon just above it representing one of the images. Any tips or suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a QLabel to show the icon and the valueChanged signal of QSlider to make the icon change.

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSlot, Qt
from PyQt4.QtGui import QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QSlider, QApplication, QPixmap


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.list_icons = ["icon1.png", "icon2.png", "icon3.png", "icon4.png", "icon5.png", "icon6.png"]

        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
        slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
        lay.addWidget(self.label)
        lay.addWidget(slider)
        slider.setMaximum(len(self.list_icons)-1)
        slider.valueChanged.connect(self.on_change_value)
        self.on_change_value(0)

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_change_value(self, value):
        icon = self.list_icons[value]
        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap(icon))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**Update:**

It is not necessary to calculate the position, you should only use Qt Style Sheet.

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSlot, Qt
from PyQt4.QtGui import QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QSlider, QApplication, QPixmap


class IconSlider(QSlider):
    def __init__(self, icons, *args, **kwargs):
        QSlider.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.icons = icons
        self.setMaximum(len(self.icons)-1)
        self.valueChanged.connect(self.on_change_value)
        self.on_change_value(0)

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_change_value(self, value):
        icon = self.icons[value]
        self.setStyleSheet('''
                QSlider::handle:horizontal{{
                    image: url({});
                    margin: -4px 0;
                }}
            '''.format(icon))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = IconSlider(["icon1.png", "icon2.png", "icon3.png", "icon4.png", "icon5.png", "icon6.png"], Qt.Horizontal)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That's helpful.  But what I'm most interested in is how to position the icon just above the actual slider's main control.  Wonder how I'd get the actual X-position of the slider control, perhaps via mapTo() function?  Mind you that's not the same as the value() or (i think) the sliderPosition().

Comment: That's cool! I might use it that way, but I had intended for the icon image to float just above the slider's main tick,etc. but I'll use your suggestion and explore a stylesheet solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: Btw, are you on Windows? On Linux, the stylesheet errors with "ValueError: zero length field name in format".  However, we're on the older Python 2.6 / PyQt4.8.

Comment: lol, good for you! :-)  What worked for me is: self.setStyleSheet('''QSlider::handle:horizontal{{ image: url({icon}); margin: -4px 0; }}'''.format(icon=icon))

Comment: Just to add, I think I may have found something helpful, thought I'd return the favor ;-) https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/4.8/qstyle.html#sliderPositionFromValue

Comment: To your function, I added the last two lines:   
    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_change_value(self, value):
        icon = self.icons[value]
        self.setStyleSheet('''QSlider::handle:horizontal{{ image: url({icon}); margin: -4px 0; }}'''.format(icon=icon))

        val = QStyle.sliderPositionFromValue(self.minimum(), self.maximum(), value, self.width())
        print val